# Does migration in a DB automatically gets reflected in read replica?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, read-replication

I created a read replica from Postgres DB in AWS RDS. Now if I run a migration in main DB will the read replica automatically migrate?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the read replica will be automatically updated after the migration is committed on the primary server.  It is just using postgres' built-in replication features.